# Search bar widget custom design?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a custom search exactly like image below.

Thanks very much

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new xml layout and replace with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#F8F8F8"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="null"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:textColorHint="#465064"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/more_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

change icons according to that you want